# Is it possible to have only one .i file for an entire project?

Tags: java, c++, swig

I am trying to create Python and Java interfaces based on C++ using SWIG. So far I was able to create a simple Java program that was able to call my `SubwordEncoder`. However, I would like to be able to have only **one** `Interface.h` and **one** `Interface.i` if that is possible.

Below is the entire code which I am using right now to generate my files.

I don't really know if what I am trying to achieve is actually a good idea or whether I should do it differently. Any recommendations would be great.

**SubwordEncoder.h**

```
#ifndef ITRANSLATE_XLIB_SUBWORDENCODER_H
#define ITRANSLATE_XLIB_SUBWORDENCODER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class SubwordEncoder {
public:
    std::vector<int> encode(std::string decoded);
    std::string decode(std::vector<int>& encoded);
};

#endif //ITRANSLATE_XLIB_SUBWORDENCODER_H
```

**SubwordEncoder.cpp**

```
#include "SubwordEncoder.h"

std::vector<int> SubwordEncoder::encode(std::string decoded) {
    std::cout << "Encoding input string: " << decoded << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> vect;
    vect.push_back(888);
    return vect;
}

std::string SubwordEncoder::decode(std::vector<int>& encoded) {
    return nullptr;
}
```

**CrazySubwordEncoder.h**

```
#ifndef ITRANSLATE_XLIB_CRAZYSUBWORDENCODER_H
#define ITRANSLATE_XLIB_CRAZYSUBWORDENCODER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class CrazySubwordEncoder {
public:
    std::vector<int> encode(std::string decoded);
    std::string decode(std::vector<int>& encoded);
};

#endif //ITRANSLATE_XLIB_CRAZYSUBWORDENCODER_H
```

**CrazySubwordEncoder.cpp**

```
#include "CrazySubwordEncoder.h"

std::vector<int> CrazySubwordEncoder::encode(std::string decoded) {
    std::cout << "I AM CRAZY !!!!!" << decoded << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> vect;
    vect.push_back(1337);
    return vect;
}

std::string CrazySubwordEncoder::decode(std::vector<int>& encoded) {
    return nullptr;
}
```

**Interfaces.h**

This header should compose all classes and interfaces which I seek to expose in other languages

```
#include "SubwordEncoder.h"
#include "CrazySubwordEncoder.h"
```

**Interfaces.i**

```
/* File : InterfacesModule.i */
%module InterfacesModule

%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_string.i"

%template(IntegerList) std::vector<int>;
%template(DoubleList) std::vector<double>;
%template(FloatList) std::vector<float>;

%{
#include "Interfaces.h"
%}

%include "SubwordEncoder.h"
%include "CrazySubwordEncoder.h"
```

**build.sh**

This script is just for now and will be replaces by a Makefile.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
set -o xtrace

SWIG_JAVA_OUT_DIR=dist/java
SWIG_PYTHON_OUT_DIR=dist/python

# Create Java directories
mkdir -p ${SWIG_JAVA_OUT_DIR}/src
mkdir -p ${SWIG_JAVA_OUT_DIR}/lib

# Run SWIG to generate Java files
swig -c++ -java -outdir ${SWIG_JAVA_OUT_DIR}/src -o ${SWIG_JAVA_OUT_DIR}/Interfaces_wrap.cpp src/Interfaces.i

# Compile library
g++ -fPIC -c src/*.cpp ${SWIG_JAVA_OUT_DIR}/Interfaces_wrap.cpp -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux/ -Isrc/ -std=c++0x

g++ -shared CrazySubwordEncoder.o SubwordEncoder.o Interfaces_wrap.o -o ${SWIG_JAVA_OUT_DIR}/lib/libxlib.so
```

This is the current output of the process above:

```
dist/
└── java
    ├── Interfaces_wrap.cpp
    ├── lib
    │   └── libxlib.so
    └── src
        ├── CrazySubwordEncoder.java
        ├── DoubleList.java
        ├── FloatList.java
        ├── IntegerList.java
        ├── InterfacesModule.java
        ├── InterfacesModuleJNI.java
        └── SubwordEncoder.java
```

Comment: Your final link step is missing `CrazySubwordEncoder.o`.

Comment: @Botje ah yes, that was missing. Thank you. Will adapt my question.

Comment: I don't get the question. In your question, you have one `Interfaces.h` and one `Interfaces.i`. Is something not working ?

Comment: @Fifi Actually, now that we're talking about this - I'm there. It actually works. I had so many issues that I didn't notice that I finally have a solution in front of me :D the only thing that's left to answer maybe is whether this is a good idea. I don't know if I am "misusing" SWIG if I force everything in one header/interface file.

Comment: @displayname Ok, then I guess it is your choice. With one interface file, you will not "misuse" SWIG (in the doc, I have rarely see them talking about multiple interface file), but maybe it will be better for you to have multiple interfaces (if there are some functions that you (almost) never use for example).

Comment: @Fifi Okay, I see. Well the idea behind having only on `.i` file would be to avoid that a "new programmer" would have to know a lot about swig. That's probably a bit idealistic but I'd like to hide this whole build process and make it feel like a "pure C++" project (if possible).

Comment: I got to say my C++ is very rusty - to say the least. I am not very familiar with the toolchains coming along with it ..

Comment: @displayname Yes, this is a very good reason to have one interface file. If there are just `%include`s and few `%template`s inside it, another developper will have no problem to understand it (and in many cases he will not have to understand it at all).

Comment: @Fifi Alright then! Thanks for giving that input. I will keep my question here though because other might find it useful how to make a small example as shown above :)

Comment: I have a couple of applications, where I have used libraries both as native C/C++ and their swig-wrapped counterparts, e.g. when embedding an interpreter (using an external runtime). For these applications I have created multiple swig libraries sharing a common type library. See e.g. http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Modules.html#Modules_nn2